# How to alias array deconstruction in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

hello is is possible to create alias for ref :

```js
const [ref, {top, right, bottom, left }] = useMeasure();
```

i tried using : and as and it didn't work

```
const [ref : name, {top, right, bottom, left }] = useMeasure();
const [ref as name, {top, right, bottom, left }] = useMeasure();
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use array destructuring assignment you are assigning the name right then and there. If you want the first array element "ref" to be named `name`, then destructure it as such.

```
const [name, {top, right, bottom, left }] = useMeasure();
```

See [Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring) for more details.